# How to decide numClasses parameter to be passed to Random Forest algorithm in SPark MLlib with pySpark

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on `Classification` using `Random Forest` algorithm in `Spark` have a sample `dataset` that looks like this:

```
Level1,Male,New York,New York,352.888890
Level1,Male,San Fransisco,California,495.8001345
Level2,Male,New York,New York,-495.8001345
Level1,Male,Columbus,Ohio,165.22352099
Level3,Male,New York,New York,495.8
Level4,Male,Columbus,Ohio,652.8
Level5,Female,Stamford,Connecticut,495.8
Level1,Female,San Fransisco,California,495.8001345
Level3,Male,Stamford,Connecticut,-552.8234
Level6,Female,Columbus,Ohio,7000
```

Here the last value in each row will serve as a `label` and rest serve as `features`. But I want to treat `label` as a category and not a number. So `165.22352099` will denote a category and so will `-552.8234`. For this I have encoded my `features` as well as `label` into categorical data. Now what I am having difficulty in is deciding what should I pass for `numClasses` parameter in `Random Forest` algorithm in `Spark` `MlLib`? I mean should it be equal to number of unique values in my `label`? My label has like `10000` unique values so if I put `10000` as value of `numClasses` then wouldn't it decrease the performance dramatically?

Here is the typical signature of building a model for Random Forest in MlLib:

```
model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                     numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                     impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the fact that you are doing something that you should not do. You problem is clearly a regression/ranking, not a classification. Why would you think about it as a classification? Try to answer these two questions:

- Do you have at least 100 samples per each **value** (100,000 * 100 = 1,000,000)?
- Is there completely no structure in the classes, so for example - are objects with value "200" **not** more similar to those with value "100" or "300" than to those with value "-1000" or "+2300"?

If at least one answer is **no**, then you **should not treat this as a classification problem**.

If for some weird reason you answered twice **yes**, then the answer is: "yes, you should encode each distinct value as a different class" thus leading to 10000 unique classes, which leads to:

- extremely imbalanced classification (RF, without balancing meta-learner will nearly always fail in such scenario)
- extreme number of classes (there are no models able to solve it, for sure RF will not solve it)
- extremely small dimension of the problem- looking at as small is your number of features I would be surprised if you could predict from that binary classifiaction. As you can see how irregular are these values, you have 3 points which only diverge in first value and you get completely different results:

  ```
  Level1,Male,New York,New York,352.888890
  Level2,Male,New York,New York,-495.8001345
  Level3,Male,New York,New York,495.8
  ```

So to sum up, with nearly 100% certainty **this is not a classification problem**, you should either:

- regress on last value (keyword: reggresion)
- build a ranking (keyword: learn to rank)
- bucket your values to at most 10 different values and then - classify (keywords: imbalanced classification, sparse binary representation)

Comment: I tried to treat this problem as a regression using RF only and treat labels as numeric values rather than encoding them (I only encoded features) but the performance is very poor (RMSE is around 70-80). My guess was that having negative values was causing the performance to drop. So I thought of trying the classification approach. And for each value I might have like more than 300 samples in my complete data. If I encode the labels also in regression will it affect the performance?

Comment: well this is a wrong way to do. classification will never be better at regressing than regression itself. This is not how one should approach the problem. Also, negative values do not matter in regression, they are as good as positive ones. My best guess would be - you have to gather much more features, your current problem, which boils down to having each vector represented as 4 ones in a high-dimensional space does not seem informative enough to predict a continuous value. Especially that City implies a state, so this gives even less knowledge than the others.

Comment: Actually in my actual code I am using a set of 12 different features and the data is a bit different than the sample I have shown above (couldn't post actual data due to restrictions so its a representation).